# In which version of Blade Runner (1982) did Gaff say this alternate dialogue at the end of the movie?

Tags: episode-identification, blade-runner-series, blade-runner

By the end of the movie *[Blade Runner (1982)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_Runner)*, the following conversation happens between Gaff and Deckard:

> **Gaff:** You've done a man's job, sir! I guess you're through, huh?
> **Deckard:** Finished.

However, I remember watching an alternate version of that scene, where things happened slightly differently.

In the original scene, there is a close-up on Deckard's face, as you hear Gaff yell his first line, before the camera switches over to the latter as he asks his question, and a police spinner is visibly parked in the background.

In the alternate scene I watched, the camera was focusing on Gaff from the beginning, and you could see a police spinner slowly landing, instead of already being parked there. And then Gaff said the following line after stretching his neck forward/upward:

> **Gaff:** You've done a man's job, sir! But are you sure you are a man?

Which is quite similar to the line he was supposed to say according to an early draft of the movie, the only difference being that the draft also had him say an additional line afterwards: "It's hard to be sure who's who around here."

Since that alternate scene was never used in any released version of the movie, and I am convinced it was not a dream, where did that scene come from?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if story-identification nor episode-identification tags are relevant. I know which movie it is, but I don't remember where I saw that scene.

Comment: For reference, apparently there are 7 different version.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versions_of_Blade_Runner unless you were a member of the studio personnel for the  four-hour-long "early cut"

Comment: For what it's worth, the only official version of the movie I watched was _The Final Cut_ which did not include that scene I saw _somewhere_

Comment: According to IMDB, the scene is *described* in Dangerous Days, but the scene itself was never shot

Comment: *Dangerous Days: The Making of Blade Runner* was included in the Final Cut DVD extras, so it's possible (in fact downright likely) that that's what you're remembering. I'm just trying to track down the quote

Comment: I'm confused at the part you said "Since that alternate scene was never used in any released version of the movie... where did that scene come from?" if it was never released, how in the world would you have ever seen it? it had to be available with at least one format or on some capacity, right, even if it's a commentary or making-of disk that shows multiple takes of that scene. is that what you mean, that it might be part of a document. or something?

Comment: @FluffyFlareon What I meant was that it was not in an official movie release, as in, neither the original, the Director's Cut, the Final Cut, etc. So, yeah, implicitly, it must have been _somewhere else_, which seems to be the case since you found it.

Comment: I got confused between that and the question's phrasing thinking you were asking about an actual full movie (an unofficial cut), which is low likely. most never see that. I may have also misread something, at least we have an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it.

*Dangerous Days*, 2:16:57 to 2:17:12.

You can watch it here: https://archive.org/details/dangerous.days.making.blade.runner.2007.480p.dvdrip.aac.h.265sermov

I've uploaded a version

Comment: [Ahem](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/275315/in-which-version-of-blade-runner-1982-did-gaff-say-this-alternate-dialogue-at#comment759279_275315)

Comment: you didn't find time stamp or upload it...! though it was a helpful remark. after starting that feature, somehow I managed to find it soon even if it was partially luck. so thanks

Comment: @FluffyFlareon plus you actually posted an answer instead of a comment, which is the right thing to do. So have your +1... You've done a man's job, sir!